# Error with 'int' object is not iterable in function

Tags: python

The error of this code is 'int' object is not iterable.

What should I do to fix this problem?

```
def printTable(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        for item in row:
            print(item, end="  ")
        print()
```

The output should be like this:

0 1 0

0 0 1

1 0 0

Comment: Please provide an example input that causes an error (like what `matrix` you passed into the function).

Comment: we cannot help you without more details, please add a [mcve] and the full traceback. `matrix` or `row`  may be some lists of integers

Comment: You are probably passing in a `list` when you should be passing in a `list of lists` (matrix)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can probably find an answer to your problem in like 90% of all of the two thousand questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=int%20object%20not%20iterable)...

Comment: Probably you are not using a `list` of `list`, probably just a simple list like `[1,2,3]`. Please, be sure that you matrix is something like `[[1],[2],[3]]`

Comment: Pretty sure he just wants to emulate the cool looking screen from the film "The Matrix"

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
numbers = [0,1]
for x in range(10):
    print(''.join([str(random.choice(numbers)) for x in range(43)]))
```

If you only want three numbers then change the `for x in range(43)` to just 3 instead of 43.

Explanation:

We use random to randomly pick a number from another list containing only 0 and 1.

We ask python to print a string of sorts. `''.join(list)` means join my list together with no spaces. But, because python is so strongly typed, when we randomly choose an int from the lust `numbers` we must convert the int to a string.

`for x in range(43)` simply means, give me 43 random numbers picked from 0 or 1.

All of it together, print a joined list of random numbers chosen out of 0 or 1 and print the result.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me, is there any chance that there is an issue with how you structed your `matrix`? I made assumptions based on how I expected it to appear in your code

```
def print_table(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        for item in row:
            print(item, end="   ")
        print()

some_matrix = [[0,1,0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]
print_table(some_matrix)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 split.py 
> 0   1   0   
> 0   0   1   
> 1   0   0
> ```